# expected identifier or '(' in C

Tags: c, cs50

I have recently started following the CS50 course on Edx. I'm stuck on the second problem set as when I try to compile my code, this message comes up:

```
expected identifier or '(' in C
```

If you need my code, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])

int key;

{

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        key = atoi(argv[1]);

        if (key == 0 || key < 0)
        {
            printf("error");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", key);
        }
    }
}
```

If there is anything else wrong with my code, could you please hint it for me?

Comment: hint: minimal example?

Comment: "If you need my code", we pretty much always need you code in a situation like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration `int key` inside the brackets of `main`.

Then change the `string argv[]` argument of main to `char* argv[]`. `string argv[]` is simply not correct for a `main` signature.

You also need to include stdio.h and stdlib.h.

Your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int key;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        key = atoi(argv[1]);

        if (key == 0 || key < 0)
        {
            printf("error");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", key);
        }
    }
}
```

Verified with [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f0b0122b337a26c)

Comment: Note that if the code included the `<cs50.h>` header, there'd be `typedef char *string;` provided, and the `main()` would be 'OK' (assuming you accept that the typedef is valid, which those taking the course need to do).

Answer (score 3):

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
  int key;
```

needs to be inside the bracket

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should look like:

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{            // <-- every function definition begins with {
    int key;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        key = atoi(argv[1]);

        if (key == 0 || key < 0)
        {
            printf("error");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", key);
        }
    }
}
```

Your question is a simple typigraphical error, and hence it should probably be closed.  I posted the full code because I could not show this in a single comment.